# Allure Framework - How to take the screenshots into the folder

Tags: robotframework, allure

I want to take the captured screenshots into the folder. In the robot framework I did it by using the below command;

robot -d TestResults/LoginFolder Test/Login.robot

Now, I want to do the same thing using allure framework. I have attached my code.

```
 [Arguments]     ${Email}  ${Password}  

    input text    ${LOCATOR_Email}    ${Email}
    capture page screenshot
    input text    ${LOCATOR_Password}    ${Password}
    capture page screenshot
    Click element  xpath=//div[3]/div/button[2]
    Sleep  20s
```

Now I have compiled code by using below command;

robot --listener 'allure_robotframework;./TestResult/Login' Test/Login.robot

When I run the code by using above command, all the screenshots are saving with excel sheets and there is no any folder for excel sheets.

What I am doing wrong? How can I take all the screenshots into one folder. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the `--outputdir foo/baz/` cli argument.

Comment: To use this, do I need to install the Allure CLI java application?? And, Can you give me small example. I mean, for where can I use this (--outputdir foo/baz/) argument?

Comment: Finally, I could resolve the screenshot issue with your answer. I used the below command;                      
"     robot --outputdir TestResults/Screenshots --listener 'allure_robotframework;./TestResults/Login' Test/Login.robot     "                                     Thank you very much for your help.